# Fix Opera displaying many pages with gigantic font size?

Tags: mac, browser, fonts, opera, macos-sierra

Opera browsers such as Opera Developer 54 on my Mac are displaying many pages with huge font sizes, ten times expected size. I wonder if it is some kind of bug related to Opera misinterpreting pages as being for a small mobile device rather than a desktop computer with a 4K monitor.

Ironically, even their own opera.com page exhibits the problem in Opera yet displays fine in Safari. Here is a dual screenshot of a Safari window nested within boundaries of a Opera window on a 4K monitor. Both point to the same page: https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/

[image: screenshot of a Safari window nestled within borders of a Opera window with both pointed to same page]

Comment: Did you check what you've defined as "font size" and "minimum font size" in Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a bug, now fixed in Version: 60.0.3255.4.